# opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++, path

I followed this video tutorial for installing OpenCV for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2015 (14) under Windows 10. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SM5OD2pZKY
However I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Category    Source  Suppression State   Tool
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory    CannyStill1 c:\users\mona\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\cannystill1\cannystill1\cannystill1.cpp 3   fatal   Build
```

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
Please suggest solution.

Comment: What are the settings for your Debug build? Because the screenshots show settings for the Release build, while you are compiling for Debug

Comment: According to the screenshots, the IDE is in Debug | x64 mode, whereas you have configured Release | Win32 mode. You have to configure each of these build environments separately using the drop-down combo boxes at the top of the Project Properties window. It is, unfortunately, not intuitive.

Comment: Have you added the Library dependencies where you manually point to the location of the opencv /bin/include folder ??